# Show / Hide TD based on TODAY's Date

Tags: javascript, date, events, show-hide

I'm trying to hide td based on today's date so the user could see "Register Now" button ONLY if the today's date is matched.

```
<table class="events-table" >
<thead class="events-thead">
    <tr class="events-tr">
      <th class="event-time" scope="col">Date/Time</th>
      <th class="event-description" scope="col">Event</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="events-tbody">
    <tr class="events-tr">
      <td class="events-td">4 March</td>
      <td class="events-link"> Desc. </td>
      <td class="cta-td">
        <a href="#"> Register Now</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh_obaid/h7Lt5w4x/17/).

I'm using Wordpress for the website and trying to come up with a solution using Javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post JS that you have coded? :)  StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You're expected to code by yourself first. Please update your question to show what you have done/tried so far in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `document.querySelector('.events-td').textContent == new Date().toLocaleString('en-gb',{day:'numeric',month:'long'});`

Comment: @Miu I have updated the JSFiddle.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the detailed reponse. I highly appreciate it but I'm actually on Wordpress and can't really pull the date as these are basically events that are being published through Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You want to format today's date in a way that matches the format of the date in the cell you want to find, then look through the cells for the text, e.g.

```js
// Setup
// Formaters
let formatDate1 = d => d.toLocaleString('en-gb',{day:'numeric', month:'long'});
let formatDate2 = d => d.toLocaleString('en-ca',{year:'numeric',month:'2-digit',day:'2-digit'});

// Get date for 2 days ago
let d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 2);
// Add 5 rows to table with dates
let table = document.querySelector('.events-table');
let rowTemplate = document.getElementById('eventRowTemplate');
for (let i=5; i; i--) {
  let tr = rowTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
  let td = tr.querySelector('td')
  td.textContent = formatDate1(d);
  td.setAttribute('data-eventDate',formatDate2(d));
  table.appendChild(tr);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}

// Example - Add register button to today's cell
// Get today in correct format
let s = formatDate2(new Date());
// Get the cell
let cell = document.querySelector('td[data-eventDate="' + s + '"]');
// Highlight it
cell.classList.add('highlight');
// Add a button
let button = cell.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
// Configure button
button.textContent = 'Register';
button.addEventListener('click',()=>alert('Register ' + s));
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
td {border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;}
.highlight {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="events-table"></table>

<template id="eventRowTemplate">
  <tr><td class="events-td">foo</td></tr>
</template>
```

A better way to do this is to give the cells identifiers based on the date, maybe a class, ID or data attribute (say `data-eventDate="2021-03-04"`), then you can just get that cell directly rather than having to loop over all the *events-td* cells, e.g.

```js
// Add class to cell for 4 March
let cell = document.querySelector('td[data-eventDate="2021-03-04"]')
if (cell) cell.classList.add('boldText');
// Add listeners, etc.
```

```css
.boldText {font-weight: bold}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td data-eventDate="2021-03-03">3 March
  <tr><td data-eventDate="2021-03-04">4 March
  <tr><td data-eventDate="2021-03-05">5 March
</table>
```

Of course you'd still generate the value based on today's date as for the first example, I've just hard coded it for convenience.